# text format in python-docx

Tags: python, format, python-docx

I need to enter text in 1000s word document. I found python-docx suitable for this purmose. But the string I have to enter has font color and style, like:

{\color{Red}Mr Mike}  **Bold** Class, *Italics* College, *City*

Is it possible to format that?

As an mwe,

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('doc.docx')
Name = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]
Class = ["Class1", "Class2", "Class3"]


for i in range(len(Name)):
  string = Name[i] + ", " + Class[i] + "" Class"
 # Name[i] should be red, bold, 12 pt; Classp[i] should be 12pt, italics
  for p in document.paragraphs:
    if p.text.find("REPLACE") >= 0:
      p.text = p.text.replace("REPLACE", string)
  document.save(Name[i] + '.docx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Character formatting is applied at the *run* level. So you will need to work at that level if you want "inline" differences in character formatting. In general, a paragraph is composed of zero or more runs. All characters in a run share the same character-level formatting ("font"). Pseudo-code for a possible approach is:

```
old = "foo"
new = "bar"
text = paragraph.text

start = text.find(old)

prefix = text[:start]
suffix = text[start+len(old):]

# --- assigning to `paragraph.text` leaves the paragraph with
# --- exactly one run
paragraph.text = prefix

# --- add an additional run for your replacement word, keeping
# --- a reference to it so you can set its visual attributes
run = paragraph.add_run("bar")
run.italic = True
# --- etc. to get the formatting you want ---

# --- add the suffix to complete the original paragraph text ---
paragraph.add_run(suffix)
```